# The F2 key not working in Eclipse Pydev, despite restarting

Tags: python, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, pydev

I use Eclipse for Python development and depend on the F2 function key to send lines of code to the console. Recently, F2 has stopped working in my installation of Eclipse Neon. I have tried everything I can think of to get it to work again:

- close and reopen the python module
- close and reopen Eclipse (as recommended on Stackoverflow)
- check the key bindings to make sure F2 is properly bound, unbind it, rebind it, reset to default key bindings
- reboot my computer
- install new version of Eclipse, Oxygen, twice..

In one of the newly installed Oxygens, at least the first time I press F2, it does open the pop-up asking what console to start with, but then after the console is open it does nothing.

In the Neon installation and the other Oxygen installation, F2 just does nothing, not even open a new console when none is active.

Would you have any idea I can try to get F2 back to work?

Comment: Dumb question but is your F2 key working in other programs? Windows? Could also be some other program you installed that is trapping that keypress ...

Comment: Yes, F2 works, e.g., in Excel..

Answer (score 5):

This was a racing condition (it was present on previous versions of PyDev, but became more apparent in PyDev 6.2/6.3 due to unrelated changes).

I fixed it at: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/083658f789e2f27f39c4fa6a431ab97371dd4244... so, should be fixed for 6.4 (note that the release is around 3 weeks away).

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten it back to work, by uninstalling pydev 6.3 and re-installing pydev 6.1. I'm not sure why this works as I was working in 6.2 when the issue first arose. I tried to solve it by upgrading to 6.3, but that didn't work. For some reason, downgrading back to 6.1 now makes it work again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing the updates for PyDev. In Eclipse, Help - Check for updates - install pending updates for PyDev. Now I can use F2 to run code from selection in the console.

Answer (score -1):

have the same issues after upgrading to

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)
Build id: 20180308-1800

PyDev for Eclipse 6.3.2.201803171248  org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group  Fabio Zadrozny